# Sub GoFC() in module refering to more than one shtName-hyperlinked shapes to hidden sheets

Tags: excel, vba

completely new to VBA, would appreciate help with the following problem:

Currently using `Sub GoFC()` in module to hyperlink shapes on a worksheet ("Menu") to other hidden worksheets (shapes and worksheet text match)

I would like to use `Sub GoFC()` for shapes in more than one sheet, but the code refers only to one sheet by name. In other words I want for the worksheet "Menu" and worksheet "Menu2" to allow all the shapes in them to run the same macro.

I sincerely hope this makes sense.

This is the code in module:

```
Sub GoFC()
    shtName=Sheets("Menu").Shapes(Application.Caller).TextFrame2.TextRange.Text
    Sheets(shtName).Visible = True
    Application.Goto Sheets(shtName).Range("A1")
End Sub
```

This is the code in the worksheet "Menu":

```
Private Sub Worksheet_FollowHyperlink(ByVal Target As Hyperlink)
    Dim shtName As String
    'shtName = Target.Name
    If InStr(1, Target.SubAddress, "'") = 1 Then
        Sh = Mid(Target.SubAddress, 2, Len(Target.SubAddress) - 5)
    Else
        Sh = Left(Target.SubAddress, InStr(1, Target.SubAddress, "!") - 1)
    End If

    Sheets(Sh).Visible = True
    Sheets(Sh).Select
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe like that

```
Sub GoFC()
Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim shtName As String
Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
Set sht = wb.ActiveSheet

    shtName = sht.Shapes(Application.Caller).TextFrame2.TextRange.Text
    If Not wsExists(shtName, wb) Then wb.Sheets.Add.Name = shtName
    wb.Sheets(shtName).Visible = True
    wb.Sheets(shtName).Activate
    wb.Sheets(shtName).Range("A1").Select
 End Sub

Function wsExists(wsName As String, wb As Workbook) As Boolean
Dim ws
    For Each ws In wb.Sheets
        wsExists = (wsName = ws.Name): If wsExists Then Exit Function
    Next ws
End Function
```

Comment: Hey, thank you for quick response. I tried that, but it stops at  shtName = sht.Shapes(Application.Caller).TextFrame2.TextRange.Text, with info the element has not been found. Any ideas?

Comment: `.TextFrame2.TextRange.Text,` has no that atribute maybe. show the file

Comment: Hey, this part of code was also present in the original code and worked perfectly

Comment: How you use GoFC()? from which page?